# How do you keyboard focus on a specific item?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am making a game where I need a constant keyboard listener (to navigate through the game). I tried getting the keyboard focus to one place and let it stay there using a seperate thread in a while true loop. This seems to crash my program.

Question:
Is there a method to get my keyboard focused on one element so I can grab my key input from there?

What can I use?:

- something that works without throwing exceptions
- something I can use in combination with other text input
- something that doesn't take hours to compile
- something that is easy to build another program (im not super good at c#)

What have I tried?

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Thread keyboardfocus = new Thread(GetFocus);
    keyboardfocus.Start();
}
private void GetFocus()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Keyboard.Focus(KeyboardButton);
    }
}

private void KeyboardButton_OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Z)
    {
        map.PosUp -= 1;
        MainCanvas.Background = Brushes.Aqua;
    }
    else if (e.Key == Key.S)
    {
        map.PosUp += 1;
        MainCanvas.Background = Brushes.Black;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What does "keyboard focused on one element" mean? What is an element in this context? (Clarify by editing your question please).

Comment: Its a button. Its called keyboardButton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add event handler for `Window.Loaded` and set there a focus to the desired control:

```
private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Keyboard.Focus(KeyboardButton);
}
```

Add event handler for the `UIElement.LostKeyboardFocus` in your case `KeyboardButton` and just set the keybord focus again to the `KeyboardButton`:

```
private void KeyboardButton_LostKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Keyboard.Focus(KeyboardButton);
}
```